# How can I add a cocoapod as a submodule rather than using it via cocoapods?

Tags: xcode, cocoapods, git-submodules

I am wanting to add a cocoapod as a dependency within my Xcode project. However, I am trying to avoid using cocoapods within my project for various reasons. How can I add the pod to my project like a submodule as an alternative?

The cocoapod that I'm attempting to use is [InstagramKit](https://github.com/shyambhat/InstagramKit). I attempted to install the git repository as a submodule, which worked fine. Once there I tried adding the entire cocoapods project to my xcode project. I added it as a project dependency, but the build fails with no indication as to what went wrong. I did run pod install on the InstagramKit project that I added to my project. So all of its dependencies were properly configured. Any idea how I can add this to my project?

Comment: The instagramKit may have other dependencies which may be unfulfilled by just adding the project and not the workspace.

Comment: "but the build fails with no indication as to what went wrong" I find this a bit dubious, could you provide the error message that you're getting from Xcode?

Comment: @KakshilShah is correct, InstagramKit has AFNetworking as a dependency listed in its podspec. If you want to avoid using Cocoapods, I'd suggest trying [Carthage](https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage) for your dependency management instead. It's a lot less intrusive compared to Cocoapods (doesn't modify your project file), and InstagramKit is Carthage-compatible.